# Why won't for ... in loop here?

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a variable containing N objects. For each object, I wish to pass these to a child component - so we will have N amount of child components with different props as well.

Parent:

```
    renderBrandCards() {

        const { marketData } = this.state;

        let i = 0;
        for (const stock in marketData){
            i++;
            return (
                <BrandCard
                    key={i}
                    stock_name={stock}
                    stock_data={marketData[stock]}
                />
            )
        }
   }
   // .... render etc
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            {this.renderBrandCards()}
        </ScrollView>
    )
```

However, only the first object of `marketDataMap` gets passed to `BrandCard` component and rendered. It doesn't loop.

Am I using `for ... in` wrong here?

Comment: You should use `array#map` for this.

Comment: You're using `return` inside the loop. A return statement can only be evaluated once each time the function is called. Returning multiple times inside a loop is useless/meaningless.`return` ends the execution of the function

Comment: @JonasW., seems to be object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I using for ... in wrong here?

Yes, because you're are returning from function after **first** step of **for** loop.

You have to create an array which will contains all the desired items and then just **return** the array.

```
let i = 0;
let brandCards = [];
for (const stock in marketData){
        i++;
        brandCards.push(
            <BrandCard
                key={i}
                stock_name={stock}
                stock_data={marketData[stock]}
            />
        )
}
return brandCards;
```

But I recommend you to use another approach with `map` method.

```
return Object.keys(marketData).map(function(key, i){
     return (<BrandCard key={i} stock_name={key} stock_data={marketData[key]}/>);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I must've missed something obvious :)